Using my svg images as blackboard bold characters
I've become dissatisfied with AMS's blackboard bold after noticing the R and Q differ a lot from Latin Modern's (and for its lack of bold numbers). I then learned it is not based on Computer Modern/Latin Modern, but on Times. Alternatives to AMS blackboard bold, like those from the packages mmboard and bbm, do not look good in my opinion. So I have created (on Inkscape) a blackboard bold font based on Latin Modern bold, as you can see in the image below. In the image, the first line is AMS's blackboard bold, in the second line is my blackboard bold, and in the last line is Latin Modern bold for comparison.

So now I want to try and use my font in LaTeX. I have the svg files of each character, but have not created a proper .otf font file. I am working on a project at the moment and I use pdfLaTeX, so I rather not change to XeLaTeX to use fontspec (should I?). Besides that, for that I would have to create the font file, which I do not know very well how to do.
So I am thinking of inserting each character as an image file, as suggested on this answer: How would I insert an .svg image as a symbol into latex?
But I also want to be able to selected the letters on the final pdf file, so my idea is to superimpose a transparent character of the original AMS \mathbb and the svg image of my character, to obtain a "fake" character. Here is what I have tried this:
${\transparent{0.0}\mathbb{N}} \kern-.5em\includesvg[height=10.5pt]{CMBB-N}$

So here are my questions:

Is including an image and superimposing it with a transparent character a bad idea for any reason I am ignorant of?
How can I scale and position the svg image so that it aligns to the baseline of text and is perfectly on top of the transparent character?
Do I have to use \mathord or a command like that to ensure the spacing behaviour of the transparent character inside math environment is correct?


don't use a transparent character supply the actual text (preferably the unicode double struck ℕ  fir cut and paste actualtext eg via the accsupp package, but I suspect that you can more easily just find a fint that you prefer and use that

the dsfont package double struck fonts are designed to be more like cm its documentation says "And there is this font, too, which was designed to be as similar to the
Computer Modern family of fonts by Donald E. Knuth as possible. Which of
these options you prefer is a matter of personal taste, so read on to ﬁnd out
whether you like this font."

I haven't been able to find a font I prefer. I don't really like the bb of dsfont.

I'll have a look at the accsupp pckage. CTAN seems to be offline right now...

you should have it installed locally unless you have a very mininmal installation. It's up to you here but I would definitely use a font. It is text after all. Importing it as vector graphics then internally hiding that and trying  to repair the accessibility damage by re-inserting text may work but it's always going to be suboptomal.
